# Different ID readings for NfcA type mifare card

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I've developed an android application to read mifare cards with a NFC reader. There is no problem about it. Application works fine. Reads and displays ID value of mifare card

I have a card reader device attached to my pc also (keyboard emulated)

But card reader and app displaying different IDs
card reader says : 0992194657 app says : 61B0233B

is there any conversion or something?

Comment: If you convert 0992194567 to hex, you get 0x3B23B061. You can find the value of your app by swapping some bytes. Si I guess you need to figure the correct sequence of the bytes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RFID algorithm to get card ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798566/rfid-algorithm-to-get-card-id)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert bytes arrays to Hex String as follows.

```
  public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

then call

```
Tag mTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);;
bytesToHex(mTag.getId())
```

Kolay gelsin:)